# internal mechanism of <bgsound> tag in html

Tags: html

what is the internal mechanism of `<bgsound>` tag html?

Comment: Because using a <bgsound> tag means you're using a heavily outdated IE-only tag. I voted it up to cancel that vote. The question is legitimate.

Answer (score 4):

I've looked into it:

For MIDI and WAV files, Internet Explorer loads winmm.dll and plays it through that. Specifically, it uses [PlaySound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712879(VS.85).aspx). For MP3 files, it uses the ActiveMovie Control, runs it through the ActiveMovie Control Type Library (Quartz.dll, for info on its functions see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms785873(VS.85).aspx)) to parse it, and plays that using DirectSound (DSOUND.DLL). Well, there you go.

Answer (score 3):

The internal mechanism is entirely up to the browser vendor (should they choose to implement this non-standard element).

It is a black box, and shouldn't matter to anybody not developing the browser itself.

Comment: It shouldn't matter, but I for one would be interested to know how M$ do it

Comment: Since Internet Explorer is not open source, you would probably have to join the IE team to find out

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by internal mechanism, because bgsound is IE only and they keep there sources closed, but other vendors use embed instead of bgsound. What are you trying to do?

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Music</title>    
    <bgsound src="sound.mid" loop="infinite"> <!-- MS. Instead of infinite you can use a number. -->
  </head>
  <body>    
    <embed src="sound.mid" autostart="true" loop="true" hidden="true" height="0" width="0"> <!-- Others.  -->
  </body>
</html>
```